# this._get is not a function - javascript oop and prototypes

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I'm using something similar to NodeJS called bondi, it's build on the Firefox js engine.. Basically i'm getting this error and I believe it's due to the way i'm referencing "this" in the .Get function below.

Basically there is a tool called SFtpClient. It has the method of "Get", to list the contents of a folder, but I want to change the prototype for this with a drop in include file. I need to change it so that it 
a/ retries several times when it fails, and b/ it has a recursive folder listing function.

So I used the prototype to change it - moved .Get to ._Get.

Can anyone see why I would be getting the error:

```
Jan 23 04:51:34 beta bondi: === this._Get is not a function --- Prio(6) Result(0x0) File(/home/nwo/approot/include/sftpclientenh
```

when I run the code below?
Thanks

```
SFtpClient.prototype._Get = SFtpClient.prototype.Get;
SFtpClient.prototype.Get = function(Folder, Retries){

    //defaults
    if(!Retries) Retries = 5;
    if(!Folder) Folder = "~/";

    //vars
    var FileListing = [];

    var connect = function(){ 
        //TODO JRF 19.01.2012 : re-enable this when bondi is fixed
        // this.HomeDirectory.replace(/\/?$/, "/");
        FileListing = this._Get(Folder);

        return true;
    }

    var i = 1;
    do{
       var res = false;
       try {
        res = connect();
       }catch(e){
           Debug.LogInfo(e.message); 
       }
       i++;
       Server.Sleep(i*2000);
    } while(res==false && i < Retries);

    return FileListing;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `res = connect.call(this)` instead of `res = connect()`.

Comment: What happens if there is an argument i need to supply to connect() ? not in this case, but in the future?

Comment: `connect.call(this, arg1, arg2 /* etc */)`. basically `.call()` takes one more argument than `()`, and that first argument tells it what `this` would be.

Comment: You can also use `.apply()` which is exactly the same as `.call()` but it takes an array of arguments as it's second parameter: `connect.apply(this, [arg1, arg2, /* etc */])`.  Great for simulated `super` calls like `this._originalPrototypeFunction(this, arguments)`